# Is there any way to get Tomcat to drop privileges after binding to privileged ports?

Tags: apache, security, tomcat, privileges

We have a development team that wants to drop the Apache front end to a website they maintain and use Tomcat only. This site will be accessible from the public Internet and have to support SSL on port 443. Apache httpd also currently redirects port 80 -> 443 but that is more of a convenience for the clients than a requirement.

Right now httpd takes care of the SSL and SNI as well as managing a few headers such as CSP and HSTS. It uses AJP to communicate with the Tomcat instances. While the parent httpd process needs to run as root to bind to ports 80 and 443 and read the private key file, the child processes drop privileges to a restricted account (cleverly called "apache") to actually handle the client requests.

Is there a way to get Tomcat to do the same thing? Start up as root to bind to the privileged ports but drop back to a less privileged account for client requests like httpd does.

There are other available solutions such as using the F5, Barracuda WAF, or Haproxy to forward at layer 4 with port translation to the web server. I just don't want to recommend the request be denied without as honest check that using Tomcat as the web server can be done congruent with our best practices.